# Segmentation Fault on QObject cast

Tags: qt

The values are like is not null, canconvert is true and is valid. But still segmentation fault occurs when trying to cast. I am debugging and the value set might have been deleted just before setValue is called with a new value.

```
QVariant m_model = 0;
```

is a member var

```
void Handler::setValue(const QVariant &var)
{
    bool isNull = m_model.isNull();
    bool canConvert = m_model.canConvert<QObject*>();
    bool isValid = m_model.isValid();

    if(!m_model.isNull() && m_model.canConvert<QObject*>()) {
        bool sConverts = (nullptr != m_model.value<QObject*>());
    }

    m_model = var;
}
```

Can someone tell why it crashes when still m_model has some data in it.

Comment: On which line it fails?

Answer (score 0):

First some problems with your code:

`QVariant::canConvert()` returns whether the *type* of the value is convertible at all, not if the actually contained value can be converted. Example: you create a QVariant with a QString as value. Calling `myValue.canConvert<double>()` will return *true*, even if your string was "nonsense". That's because QVariant is generally able to convert strings like "1.0" to a double value of 1.0.

`QVariant::isValid()` returns whether the contained type is not `QMetaType::UnknownType`. This mostly only happens when you create a QVariant without assigning a value.

`QVariant m_model = 0;` will create a QVariant with type int. Don't do that. Just declare it without the `= 0` part. QVariant (like other value types in Qt, i.e. QString, QSize etc.) doesn't need to be initialized to be null, empty or invalid. Declaring it like you did will make `isValid()` return *true*, though you might intend it to return *false*.

That said, i'm unsure of what you want to achieve in your code snippet. Basically you're testing `m_model` **before** assigning a new *untested* value `var` to it (why???).

As you said your value `var` (or probably the contained value) might have been deleted just before `setValue()` is called. If the QObject has been deleted and the pointer has not been set to `nullptr` explicitly you're handing a QVariant with a dangling pointer to the function. As `setValue()` doesn't test the new value `var` you will have that same dangling pointer in `m_model`, resulting in a crash whenever you try accesing it.